# why is my DateTime.TryParser parsing Japanese words

Tags: c#

I am expecting a false value from a `DateTime.parse()` function with japanese input but its returning true value.

```cs
DateTime dt = new DateTime();

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse("30 分", out dt));
```

it works fine for other Japanese words for example for hour or tomorrow but when it comes to minutes `分` it returns  true.

Comment: `True` just means it successfully parsed. `30分` means "30 minutes". It will set `dt` to today's date, 30 minutes past midnight. This is equivalent to passing `00:30`. Why are you expecting `False`? (Japanese date/time formats often use kanji units, and not separators: it is now 2021年2月16日18時35分 in Japan. If you `TryParse` that, it will also be `True`.)

Comment: sorry i am new to c# and the code i am working on is written by some one else. as per the requirements the output can be either "2 時間" or "4 時間" or 30分. The code i have returns false for the hourly (時間) timings and and i then show the exact hourly timing in UI as well but for the minuites it returns true which leads to another returning the object dt from the function.(2/16/2021 12:30 am). I don't understand why  the hourly time is not parsed but the  minuites are?

Comment: I want to return 30 mins to the user,  i got the value 30分 form deepl converter. Is there any way to deal 30分 as 30 mins , like it does for 2 hours or four hours?

Comment: 時間 is "hour" as in time interval or duration. If you want intervals, `DateTime` is the wrong class, you should be using `TimeSpan` instead. Curiously, timespans do not allow kanji units: neither `30分` nor `２時間` are parsed.

Comment: when i use 30分間 instead of 30分 it works fine. but changing the 分in database is not allowed by my seniors.

Comment: The issue you're facing is down to 分 being used to express time (e.g. 2:30 / 2時３０分) and a length of time (e.g. 2 hours and 30 minutes / ２時間３０分). Because it can be used to express time, `DateTime` accepts parsing time with it. I think you'll have to write your own validation here.